# NSProgressIndicator built-in animation raises CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS

Tags: multithreading, core-animation, xcode9-beta, nsprogressindicator, xcode9

This looks like a bug in either NSProgressIndicator or Xcode 9 to me:

- Run Xcode 9 Beta 1 or Beta 4, in macOS 10.12.6.
- File > New Project, macOS, Cocoa app, Objective-C or Swift, ARC or not, no storyboards, latest (10.13) SDK.
- In the app target's environment, set `CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS=1`.
- In app delegate, add a IBOutlet `progressIndicator`.
- In the nib, add a NSProgressIndicator to the window, connect to that outlet.  Leave the checkbox *Indeterminate* switched on.
- In `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`, call `-startAnimation:` on `progressIndicator`.
- Build and run.

Expected Result:

Progress indicator should happily show indeterminate progress, because I did everything on the main thread.

Actual Result:

App crashes, citing CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS, when
 `-startAnimation:` is called.

You can see this in a [tiny demo project](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/ProgressimationDemo).

Did I do anything wrong?  Is my Expected Result incorrect?

*P.S.  I asked this on Apple's Developer Forums, but still awaiting moderator approval after 2 working days, so I deleted it and came here instead :(*

Update: Still lacking an explanation, I filed Apple Bug 33593575.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in NSProgressIndicator. Your bug report (thank you for filing!) was marked as a duplicate of an earlier bug, which was already resolved in macOS 10.13.